# update a table from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012 and I have a stored procedure which when executed inserts into a table like below

```
Column1     Column2      Column3
   AA         AA1         NULL
   AB         AB1         NULL
   AC         AC1         NULL
```

I'm having to fill in the NULL values manually (I know this is not ideal, but this is the predicament I find myself in)

```
  Column1     Column2      Column3
   AA         AA1           1234    --manual input
   AB         AB1           2468    --manual input     
   AC         AC1           3579    --manual input
```

I originally had my stored procedure set up something like this

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [usp_My_Stored_Procedure]

 AS BEGIN

 DELETE table1
 INSERT table1

 Select * from (

 select 
 Column1,Column2,Column3 
 from another table
 where Column3 IS NULL

 ) as SP

 ;
 END
```

Now when this executed its going to delete everything I've input in Column 3.  If I get rid of the 'DELETE  table1' and keep the INSERT its just going to keep duplicating everything.  I just need it to update new rows as they appear.

With help from Zaynuls answer below I have now tried the following

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [usp_My_Stored_Procedure]


AS BEGIN


MERGE Table1 as d

USING SP as s

ON (d.Column1 = S.Column1)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 

INSERT (Column1, Column2, Column3 )

VALUES (s.Column1, s.Column2, s.Column3)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 

UPDATE SET d.Column1 = s.Column1,  d.Column2 = s.Column2, d.Column3 = s.Column3

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SP THEN DELETE

Select * from (

 select 
 Column1,Column2,Column3 
 from another table
 where Column3 IS NULL

 ) as SP

 ;
 END
```

This hasn't worked, think i'm getting muddled with the source and destination.
In this case I have used the destination as the table I am inputting the data ('Table1')   And the source as the derived table name (SP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use merge like below, assume your 2 table source and destination

```
merge destination as D
using Source as S
on (D.Column1=S.Column1)
when not matched by Target then 
Insert(Column1,Column2,Column3)
Values(s.Column1,s.Column2,S.Column3)
when matched  then
Update set D.Column2=S.Column2, D.Column3=S.Column3
when not matched by Source then
Delete
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul, should my source be my derived table name?